# Copy a property that is an IDbSet<T> to a property on another class that is a List<T> with the same names using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-4.1

We have a scenario in our unit tests where we have created a FakeDbSet that implements IDbSet. In a FakeUnitOfwork I have properties that are IDbSets and getting new-ed up using the FakeDbSet.

Without having to write out each different property in my Commit method I am trying to use reflection to iterate over the properties inside the FakeUnitOfWork. I then want to copy the property values to a differnt class that has propertes of List<> of the same type. So I may have a property in my FakeUnitOfWork:

```
IDbSet<User> Users {get {return _users ?? (_users = new FakeDbSet<User>());}
```

In my fake data store I have this property:

```
List<User> Users {get;set;}
```

This is hwat I have so far:

```
public void Commit()
{ 
     foreach (var property in typeof(TestUnitOfWork).GetProperties())
            {
               var testContextType = typeof (TestDataContext).GetProperty(property.Name);
//I then want to do a ToList() on the TestUnitOfWork IDbSet properties to push them into the TestDataContext.


            }
}
```

So, I am not sure how to know I am looking at, say, a IDbSet (from FakeUnitOfWork) and a List (from my fake memory data store) so that I can copy the data from FakeUnitOfWork over to the data store. Since they have the same names I only need to figure out how to do the casting via reflection.

Update: I tried something like this and thought I might be on the irght track, but the code never gets hit:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(TestUnitOfWork).GetProperties())
                {
                   var testContextType = typeof (TestDataContext).GetProperty(property.Name);
                   if(property.GetValue(this,null) is IDbSet<MyBaseEntityType>)
                   {
                        testContextType.SetValue(TestDataContext, ((IDbSet<MyBaseEntityType>) property.GetValue(this,null)).ToList(),null);
                   }


                }
```

Comment: Too much information for me. From what I can tell, you have a mock IDbSet implemented with a HashSet that you're trying to cast to a List. Why not implement the mock IDbSet as a List and save yourself a step?

Comment: I'm tending to agree with sq33G - there seems to be a lot of information in the question which may not be directly relevant to the problem and, as a result, it's rather difficult to follow. Is it possible to isolate the problem a little more?

Comment: I cannot mock the IDbSet as a List, because of interfaces I am using that I do not have shown here.

Comment: Manual mocks?  Have you tried a library like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [Rhino.Mocks](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/rhino-mocks)?  They're admittedly not ideal for fakes that you develop for manual+isolated testing or isolating your code during development, but they're perfect for unit tests.  Also, have you thought of copying and modifying the entity templates to create your mocks using code gen?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: I am using Code First and not templates. So, that doesn't seem to be an option. I have looked at using MOQ and can still use it, but it doesn't help me with my storing of data. We also would like to use our Fake libraries outside of unit testing as well.

Comment: @DDiVita: "We also would like to use our Fake libraries outside of unit testing as well" - then you must do what you must do :)  "but it doesn't help me with my storing of data" - For unit tests using mock object frameworks like that, you don't store data because you don't do state-based testing.  Instead you do behavior-based testing, where you essentially make a new mock type for every test.  The mock returns pre-scripted data, and you just verify that calls are made to your mock, and that the correct data is passed in those calls.

Comment: If you have to copy over data from one class to another, and the properties have the same names, you might want to look into [the AutoMapper library](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Yes, I know how the frameworks function, but this is not my question. I am asking if what I want to do is possible. I truly appreciate the advice regarding a mocking Library, however, I need an answer to my question ;).

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: We are using AutoMapper in our current applications, however I am still stuck in the same situation where I'd like to iterate over the properties in one class and copy them into another. With AutoMapper, I still need to do something like this: Mapper.Map<IDbSet<User>, List<User>>(userList). I am looking for a way to not have to write out all the properties. Without having to rely on AutoMapper I can simply call ToList() on my IDbSet and copy them manually.

Comment: @DDiVita: Do all your entity types have a common method name for `UpdateFrom` and `Clone` operations?  If they don't have these, then you won't be able to use reflections to ignore the type - you'd have to do reflections and run against a manually created switch statement or dictionary for mapping entity type to clone/update methods.

Comment: @DDiVita: And how will you do a diff of the lists, so you can implement change tracking in a way that fully supports automation?  You'll need a custom comparison for each entity type based on primary key(s), and a custom comparison for each entity type based on full equality.  You'll also need to be able to retrieve those simply from the type (possibly via a property).  I was three-quarters to a pseudo-code version of the answer when I stumbled upon that issue...

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Check out my update. I thought I was on the right track, but my code doesn't get hit. I think I may just be heading towards manually setting each property. Also, I am not concerned with change tracking. Thanks so much for the thoughts and help! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a reflection to get types and properties for your context and unit of work. Now you have property of type `List<>` on one side and you want to assign content of property of type `IDbSet<>` to it. Is it right?

The theory

To do that you need to call `ToList` method on `IDbSet<>` but this method is not part of `IDbSet<>` interface. It is extension method defined in `System.Linq.Enumerable` static class. Extension method is just static method with syntactic sugar but it can still be called as normal static method. So you must lookup `Enumerable` class using reflection (get type), get generic method info for `ToList` method and target it to proper generic argument (used by current `IDbSet<>`). Then you can pass your set as parameter to this method and invoke it.

Anyway better approach would be avoiding as many reflection as possible. For example expose special interface on `TestUnitOfWork` which would offer direct access to lists.

Comment: I do mention in my code about using the ToList() extension method, I had a lot more context in this post, but other users found it too difficult to understand. So, I am using interfaces on both my UoW and data context and still don't see a good way of doing this. I am going to disregard using reflection like you stated. It's not worth it at this point ;)