# Reflecting over IDbSets using base class

Tags: c#, reflection, datacontext, dbset

I have a `DataContext` derived class that has many `IDbSet`s that are subclasses of a base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Length {get; set;}
    public int Height {get; set;}
}

public class Derived1 : BaseClass
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set}
}

public class Derived2 : BaseClass
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set}
}

public class Derived3 : BaseClass
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set}
}

public class Derived4 : BaseClass
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set}
}

public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<Derived1> set1 {get; set;}
    public IDbSet<Derived2> set2 {get; set;}
    public IDbSet<Derived3> set3 {get; set;}
    public IDbSet<Derived4> set4 {get; set;}
}
```

I actually have many more derived classes and corresponding `IDbSet`s, and I want to use reflection on the MyContext class and iterate over them to retrieve and inspect properties that exist on the base class, but when I try to cast the `IDbSet` as `IDbSet<BaseClass>` it comes back null.

```
        using (var db = new ValidationDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                Type t = db.GetType();
                if (t != null)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties())
                    {
                        var objects = (t.InvokeMember(prop.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, db, null));

                        var dbset = objects as IDbSet<BaseClass>;
                        if (dbset != null) //dbset is always null
                        {
                            dbset.Where(v => v.Length <= 0)
                                .ForEach(v => Debug.WriteLine("Bad Length"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This answer may have the key, I'll update if I figure it out from this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8475605/264607

Comment: this one also looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502088/how-to-invoke-idbsett-firstordefaultpredicate-using-reflection?rq=1

Comment: Are you saying you want to use IDbSet<Derived1> as IDbSet<BaseClass> for querying? I see you are using `dbset.Where()` in the code.

Comment: @MikeHixson basically, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDbSet<T>` is not a covariant interface, which means you can not assign `IDbSet<Derived1>` variable to `IDbSet<BaseClass>` variable. More on covariance here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

`IDbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>` which is a covariant interface and is the part of `IDbSet<T>` that you want to use for querying.

You can try replacing the line:

```
var dbset = objects as IDbSet<BaseClass>;
```

with

```
var dbset = objects as IQueryable<BaseClass>;
```

You should be able to leave the rest of the code as is.